# Call sub insertion operator

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I have a this code :

main.cpp

```
     #include <iostream>
     #include "MySmartPtr.h"
     #include "Bean.h"
     using namespace std;
     int main(int argc,char* argv[])
     {
        MySmartPointer<Bean> ptr = new Bean;
        ptr->setName("Jordan Borisov");
        cout << ptr << endl;
        return 0;
     }
```

---

MySmartPtr.h

```
     #ifndef MY_SMART_POINTER_H
     #define MY_SMART_POINTER_H
     #include <iostream>
     using namespace std;
     template<typename T>
     ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,T& o);

     template<typename T>
     class MySmartPointer
     {
     public:
        MySmartPointer()
        {
              ptr = new T;
              isOwner = true;
        };
        MySmartPointer(T* t)
        :ptr(t)
        {
        }
        ~MySmartPointer()
        {
              if (isOwner) delete ptr;
        }
        const T* getPtr() const {return ptr;}
        T& operator* () {return *ptr;}
        T* operator->() {return ptr;}


     private:
        mutable bool isOwner;
        T* ptr;
     };
     template<typename T>
     ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,T& o)
     {
     os << static_cast<const T>(o);
     return os;
     };
     #endif
```

---

Bean.h

```
     #ifndef BEAN_H
     #define BEAN_H
     #include <string>
     #include <iostream>
     using namespace std;
     class Bean
     {
     public:
        Bean();
        void setName(const string& name);
        const string& getName() const;
     private:
        string name;
     };
     #endif
```

---

Bean.cpp

```
     #include "Bean.h"
     Bean::Bean()
     :name("")
     {
     }
     const string& Bean::getName() const
     {
        return name;
     }
     void Bean::setName(const string& name)
     {
        this->name = name;
     }
     ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,Bean& o)
     {
        os << "Name :" << o.getName();
        return os;
     }
```

---

So the problem here is that in the Microsoft visual studio 2008 I have this warning :

> warning C4717: 'operator<< const >' : recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow

and of course when I debig the program in the on the cout line in the main.cpp file I press F11 and I the debuger goes to the MySmartPtr.h file in the overwritten operator function.
And in the line `os << static_cast<const T>(o);` call this operator overload again and again so I got stack overload exception. 
My question is why this is happening?

OS - Windows XP

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would you expect to happen instead?

Comment: The cout in the main.cpp must call the overwitten operator in the MySmartPtr.h which call the overwritten operator in the Bean.h file. This is my idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why this is happening?

With all due respect, it is happening because that is what you coded.

```
template<typename T>
 ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,T& o)
 {
   os << static_cast<const T>(o);
   return os;
 };
```

You wrote a recursive function template for `operator<<`, which is applicable for every possible type. It has to call itself.  Try this instead:

```
 template<typename T>
 std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const MySmartPointer<T>& o);
```

Your `operator<<` is thus limited to objects created from types instantiated from your own template, rather than *every object in the system*.

In other news, you also have `using namespace std` in your headers, and failed to declare `Bean`'s `operator<<`.

Here is a corrected version of your program:

Bean.cpp

```
 #include "Bean.h"
 Bean::Bean()
 :name("")
 {
 }
 const std::string& Bean::getName() const
 {
    return name;
 }
 void Bean::setName(const std::string& name)
 {
    this->name = name;
 }
 std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const Bean& o)
 {
    os << "Name :" << o.getName();
    return os;
 }
```

main.cpp

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include "MySmartPtr.h"
 #include "Bean.h"
 using namespace std;
 int main(int argc,char* argv[])
 {
    MySmartPointer<Bean> ptr = new Bean;
    ptr->setName("Jordan Borisov");
    cout << ptr << endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

Bean.h

```
 #ifndef BEAN_H
 #define BEAN_H
 #include <string>
 #include <iostream>
 class Bean
 {
 public:
    Bean();
    void setName(const std::string& name);
    const std::string& getName() const;
 private:
    std::string name;
 };
 std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Bean&);
 #endif
```

MySmartPtr.h

```
 #ifndef MY_SMART_POINTER_H
 #define MY_SMART_POINTER_H
 #include <iostream>

 template<typename T>
 class MySmartPointer
 {
 public:
    MySmartPointer()
    {
          ptr = new T;
          isOwner = true;
    };
    MySmartPointer(T* t)
    :ptr(t)
    {
    }
    ~MySmartPointer()
    {
          if (isOwner) delete ptr;
    }
    T* getPtr() {return ptr;}
    T& operator* () {return *ptr;}
    T* operator->() {return ptr;}
    const T* getPtr() const {return ptr;}
    const T& operator* () const {return *ptr;}
    const T* operator->() const {return ptr;}

 private:
    mutable bool isOwner;
    T* ptr;
 };
 template<typename T>
 std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const MySmartPointer<T>& o)
 {
 os << *o;
 return os;
 }
 #endif
```

Comment: Could you tell me why the second one version of MySmartPtr works?